# Graphical Modeler_ Routing Calculation

Tags: qgis, routing, qgis-modeler

I am trying to modify the QNEAT 3 plugin to make it calculate the least cost path, where the cost is not the "distance" ... I am using the "Expression" tool.

Is there a simple way to do this?